# delete records from the file using jython

Tags: jython, streamsets

How to delete n lines at top=2 and bottom=1 using jython which is saved in sample.txt. My filesize might be MB/GB.

**sample.txt contains below lines**

> ```
>    1,a
>    2,b
>    3,c
>    4,d
>    5,e
>    6,f
> ```

**Expected Output :**

> ```
> 3,c
> 4,d
> 5,e
> ```

Comment: *Can anyone suggest better way...* Better than what? What is the problem?

Comment: I have modified the context. Sorry not being question clear

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not clear what the problem is. What have you tried?

Comment: I need to read the file and skip top and bottom based on the number which we pass through jython

Comment: I understand that. But what is the PROBLEM?